# Event not shown on calendar Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, calendar

I have created event and event view using **view from template** option ([http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/calendar-in-drupal/][1]). The event are not shown within calendar on local machine. But on server they shown in calendar. Also i got error

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'data' in template_preprocess_calendar_month() (line 38 of C:\xampp\htdocs\allstate\sites\all\modules\calendar\theme\theme.inc).
Warning: Illegal string offset 'data' in template_preprocess_calendar_month() (line 43 of C:\xampp\htdocs\allstate\sites\all\modules\calendar\theme\theme.inc).
Warning: Illegal string offset 'data' in template_preprocess_calendar_month() (line 38 of C:\xampp\htdocs\allstate\sites\all\modules\calendar\theme\theme.inc).
Warning: Illegal string offset 'data' in template_preprocess_calendar_month() (line 43 of C:\xampp\htdocs\allstate\sites\all\modules\calendar\theme\theme.inc).
Warning: Illegal string offset 'data' in template_preprocess_calendar_month() (line 38 of C:\xampp\htdocs\allstate\sites\all\modules\calendar\theme\theme.inc).
Warning: Illegal string offset 'data' in template_preprocess_calendar_month() (line 43 of C:\xampp\htdocs\allstate\sites\all\modules\calendar\theme\theme.inc).
Warning: Illegal string offset 'data' in template_preprocess_calendar_month() (line 38 of C:\xampp\htdocs\allstate\sites\all\modules\calendar\theme\theme.inc).
Warning: Illegal string offset 'data' in template_preprocess_calendar_month() (line 43 of C:\xampp\htdocs\allstate\sites\all\modules\calendar\theme\theme.inc).
Warning: Illegal string offset 'data' in template_preprocess_calendar_month() (line 38 of C:\xampp\htdocs\allstate\sites\all\modules\calendar\theme\theme.inc).
Warning: Illegal string offset 'data' in template_preprocess_calendar_month() (line 43 of C:\xampp\htdocs\allstate\sites\all\modules\calendar\theme\theme.inc).
```

Please help me.

Comment: Probably different versions of calendar module (https://drupal.org/project/calendar). Notice this part: `I just added a new row plugin to the 7.3 version of Calendar that should work with any entity, not just nodes. The old plugin has been marked as deprecated and will be removed in the final release, so please update your views to use the new plugin, 'Calendar Entities'.`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the calendar module with php 5.4. There is a patch: https://drupal.org/node/1471400